# C# convert JSON result

Tags: json, parsing

I am getting this JSON back from *Box.com*:

```
{
    "total_count": 2,
    "entries": [
        {
            "type": "file",
            "id": "2615240421",
            "sequence_id": "0",
            "name": "successful file upload.png",
            "description": null,
            "size": 19586,
            "path": "/Hey Hey Whats Goin On/successful file upload.png",
            "path_id": "/316877053/2615240421",
            "created_at": "2012-07-11T11:54:21-07:00",
            "modified_at": "2012-07-11T11:54:21-07:00",
            "etag": null,
            "created_by": {
                "type": "user",
                "id": "181757341",
                "name": "sean test",
                "login": "sean+test@box.com"
            },
            "modified_by": {
                "type": "user",
                "id": "181757341",
                "name": "sean test",
                "login": "sean+test@box.com"
            },
            "owned_by": {
                "type": "user",
                "id": "181757341",
                "name": "sean test",
                "login": "sean+test@box.com"
            },
            "shared_link": null,
            "parent": {
                "type": "folder",
                "id": "316877053",
                "sequence_id": "0",
                "name": "Hey Hey Whats Goin On"
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "file",
            "id": "2615240431",
            "sequence_id": "0",
            "name": "a whole lot of shit just happenedjson.png",
            "description": null,
            "size": 128063,
            "path": "/Hey Hey Whats Goin On/a whole lot of shit just happenedjson.png",
            "path_id": "/316877053/2615240431",
            "created_at": "2012-07-11T11:54:21-07:00",
            "modified_at": "2012-07-11T11:54:21-07:00",
            "sha1": null,
            "created_by": {
                "type": "user",
                "id": "181757341",
                "name": "sean test",
                "login": "sean+test@box.com"
            },
            "modified_by": {
                "type": "user",
                "id": "181757341",
                "name": "sean test",
                "login": "sean+test@box.com"
            },
            "owned_by": {
                "type": "user",
                "id": "181757341",
                "name": "sean test",
                "login": "sean+test@box.com"
            },
            "shared_link": null,
            "parent": {
                "type": "folder",
                "id": "316877053",
                "sequence_id": "0",
                "name": "Hey Hey Whats Goin On"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I need to get the Modified information for each file.  Not sure how to do this in .NET.  I'm used to parsing XML.  I've seen a few examples on Stack, but they are usually shallow objects.  Not sure about deeper objects.

Help?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would just use the built in [JavaScriptSerializer class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx). You can deserialize your JSON to a specific type or an 'on-the-fly' type which you can then 'traverse'.